# AsyncSocket failed?

Tags: ios, asyncsocket

I am having one problem with AsyncSocket when playing and after many days I still don't have solution for this. Please check and give me any idea, this is its log:

```
0 CFNetwork 0x3431e460 CoreStreamCFStreamSupport<__CFWriteStream*, CoreWriteStream>::_stream_open(__CFWriteStream*, CFStreamError*, unsigned char*, void*) + 76
1 CoreFoundation 0x3456f3f7 _CFStreamOpen + 75
2 CoreFoundation 0x3456f3a7 _CFWriteStreamOpen + 91
3 DemoPlayer 0x003f88b1 -[AsyncSocket openStreamsAndReturnError:] (AsyncSocket.m:1819)
4 DemoPlayer 0x003f829b -[AsyncSocket doAcceptFromSocket:withNewNativeSocket:] (AsyncSocket.m:1607)
5 DemoPlayer 0x003fc4b5 -[AsyncSocket doCFSocketCallback:forSocket:withAddress:withData:] (AsyncSocket.m:4008)
6 DemoPlayer 0x003f7cf7 MyCFSocketCallback (AsyncSocket.m:4101)
7 CoreFoundation 0x345f3e5d __CFSocketPerformV0 + 605
8 CoreFoundation 0x345f1683 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
9 CoreFoundation 0x345f0f7f __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 363
10 CoreFoundation 0x345efcb7 __CFRunLoopRun + 647
11 CoreFoundation 0x34562ebd _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
12 CoreFoundation 0x34562d49 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
13 GraphicsServices 0x381132eb _GSEventRunModal + 75
14 UIKit 0x36478301 _UIApplicationMain + 1121
15 DemoPlayer 0x002108c7 main (main.m:13)
```

It is urgent, if you have any ideas, please feel free to answer me.
Thanks so much.
Ryan